# iPhone 4S iOS 7 Battery Drain

Tags: iphone, battery, ios

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.0.

Since the upgrade, my battery drains twice as fast.

I have applied all the battery saving tips available on the internet (e.g. http://osxdaily.com/2013/09/19/ios-7-battery-life-fix/).

iPhone is primarily used for phone calls, texting, email, documents/scheduling/productivity, and light web surfing.

Anyone experiencing similar issues? Any suggestions or fixes to apply?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same. It will even shut down at around 25%.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that problem with iOS 7.

Have you tried restarting or resetting your iPad?

> Restart: Press On/Off button until the Slide to Power Off slider
>   appears, select Slide to Power Off and, after the iPad shuts down,
>   then press the On/Off button until the Apple logo appears.
>
> Reset: Press the Home and On/Off buttons at the same time and hold
>   them until the Apple logo appears (about 10 seconds).

If these don't correct the problem connect to iTunes and do a restore.

**If all else fails to do so:**

In Settings, turn on Airplane mode, then reset your device by holding Power + Home button 15 seconds until you see the Apple logo. Power back on, then turn off Airplane mode.

Comment: Hi AppleDevX, my problem was only resolved when I purchased and installed a new battery into my 4S. Now, I can go for 24hrs on a single charge. In the past, the battery barely lasted for 12-15 hrs.

Comment: How old is your previous 4S battery?

Comment: My original battery was almost exactly 2 years old.